# sentence starting with should

Tags: meaning, subjunctives

What is the meaning of:

> "Should there be any interest in discussing this further someone will be in touch with you".

Why does this start with "should"?

Comment: What do you think it might mean?  Is there some particular part of it that is giving you trouble?

Comment: A few things to remember for your next question: Please provide more [details](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please) about the part of the quote that is confusing you, and tell us what words you've already looked up, and what you found. Plus, you should always [tell us where you found your sentence](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1084/so-you-found-a-sentence-or-phrase-why-you-should-cite-your-source).

Answer (score 3):

> What is the meaning of "Should there be any interest in discussing this further someone will be in touch with you".

It's probably the *Should there be* part that's confusing. *Should* often indicates some sort of suggestion or obligation, as in: *You **should** take out the garbage.* But in this case *should* indicates something that *might* happen. Another way to say the same thing would be *If there is...* So, you could read the whole thing as:

*If there is any interest in discussing this further, someone will be in touch with you.*

What they're really saying is that they'll take the next step, and you don't hear from them it's because they're not interested in pursuing the matter, whatever that is. That's often expressed as: *Don't call us, we'll call you.*

Answer (score 0):

*should* in such contexts means *if.* It is a common style in writing emails to clients.

> Should you have any query, don't hesitate to contact us.

Likewise, here, *should* means ***'if.'***

It means that if you are interested in discussing anything about it, someone will be in touch with you.

*Note: it can be grammatically improved.*

Answer (score -1):

Context will help, as it is possible that this is just a polite closing that has little meaning to it.

As written, it means that the possibility of discussing the issue in question further still exists.  If you wish to do so, contact the organization (I presume this is from one) and a representative from the organization will be in contact with you to have the discussion.

As a polite closing, it might just be there to sound like the organization would welcome further contact, but that it does not actually expect you to take advantage.  Without context, it is difficult to tell if this is the case.  As an instructor in business writing, I would certainly not recommend that someone intentionally say this unless one is serious about the possibility of it happening.  :)

Comment: It's interesting that you interpreted this in the opposite direction from what I understood. I read it to mean: "Don't call and ask about this, we'll let you know if we want to pursue it." I think the difference might be on which end you assume the interest happens: I think *Should there be interest* means *if **we** are interested* and I think you assumed that it means *if **you** are interested.*

Comment: @Caleb It is a little ambiguous.  I can't dismiss your interpretation. :)